# Trying to get data from useEffect into Flatlist to be displayed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-effect

I tried to get data from Firestore to Flatlist through useEffect but the Flatlist is not reading the data given from the useEffect.I understand that the Flatlist renders before the useEffect renders but how can I push the data from useEffect to Flatlist. This is my code. This code gets the data and updates the userPosts but the userPosts that I got from the useEffect is not being updated into the Flatlist component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import firebase from 'firebase'


function FavDiscussion(props) {

    const { currentUser, posts } = props;
    const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
    const favDiscussion = []
    

    
    useEffect(() => {
             
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("Discussion")
            .doc(currentUser.FavDiscussion[1])
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              
                setUserPosts(snapshot.data())
                
            })
        
    }, [])




    return (
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
         
            <FlatList
                horizontal={false}
                extraData={userPosts}
                data={userPosts}
                keyExtractor={userPosts => userPosts.id}
              
                renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
                
                  <View>
                        <View style={styles.gridItem} >
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('EditDeleteDiscussion', { did: item.id })}>
                                <View style={styles.container2}>

                                    <Text style={styles.faculty}>
                                        {item.faculty}
                                    </Text>
                                        
                                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                                        {item.title}
                                    </Text>
                                        
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#140F38', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },

 

     container2: {
        padding: 15,
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "flex-start"
    },


    input: {
        margin: 5,
        height: 55,
        borderColor: '#E3562A',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        width: 300,
        borderRadius: 12,
        padding: 8,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        position: "absolute",
        height: 37,
        left: 11,
        right: 49,
        top: 51,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    
    bell: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        left: 330,
        top: 59,
  
    },

    search: {
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },

    gridItem: {
        flex:1,
        margin: 15,
        width: 340,
        height: 114,
        borderRadius: 16,
       // overflow: Platform.OS ==='android' && Platform.Version>=21 ? "hidden" : 'visible',
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#003565",
    },


    faculty: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    },

    title: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    },




});

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    posts: store.userState.posts,

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(FavDiscussion);
```

Comment: Did you check, if your state has actually updated ? Try putting debuggers and console.log

Comment: Hi yes, my state has been updated, but the flatlist if not getting the updated data from the state. What i understand is the useEffect renders after the Flatlist so once the useEffect has been rendered the updated data is not being fetched by the Flatlist

Comment: Not exactly. Since you are again doing the `setUserPosts`, it should trigger re-render again. Could you make a reproducible sample using https://snack.expo.io/.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when the correct key is not provided to the Flatlist, Please add the keyExtractor like this:
`keyExtractor={item => item.id}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion indeed the keyExtractor was wrong but even after changing it no ouput has been made. Any other suggestions